# How to implement a 1D Convolutional Auto-encoder in Keras for vector data?

Tags: keras, convolution, autoencoder

My input vector to the auto-encoder is of size 128. I have 730 samples in total (730x128). I am trying to use a 1D CNN auto-encoder. I would like to use the hidden layer as my new lower dimensional representation later.
My code right now runs, but my decoded output is not even close to the original input. 
Here is the code:

```python
input_sig = Input(batch_shape=(None,128,1))
x = Conv1D(64,3, activation='relu', padding='valid')(input_sig)
x1 = MaxPooling1D(2)(x)
x2 = Conv1D(32,3, activation='relu', padding='valid')(x1)
x3 = MaxPooling1D(2)(x2)
flat = Flatten()(x3)
encoded = Dense(32,activation = 'relu')(flat)

print("shape of encoded {}".format(K.int_shape(flat)))

x2_ = Conv1D(32, 3, activation='relu', padding='valid')(x3)
x1_ = UpSampling1D(2)(x2_)
x_ = Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='valid')(x1_)
upsamp = UpSampling1D(2)(x_)
flat = Flatten()(upsamp)
decoded = Dense(128,activation = 'relu')(flat)
decoded = Reshape((128,1))(decoded)

print("shape of decoded {}".format(K.int_shape(x1_)))

autoencoder = Model(input_sig, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The input to the autoencoder is then --> (730,128,1)
But when I plot the original signal against the decoded, they are very different!!
Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Did the loss decrease both for training and validation dataset?

Comment: @hikaru, yes, it does slightly. Do I have the correct intuition about the decoder (deconvolution and upsampling)?

Comment: Where do you subsequently use `encoded` in your model? Shouldn't that be connected to the decoder?

Comment: was this ever resolved? I would like to do something similar except my 1-D vectors are 3000 long....

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a single channel convolution layer with "sigmoid" activation to reconstruct the decoded image. 
Take a look at the example below. You can compile it with the loss='mse' and optimizer='adam'

```
input_sig = Input(batch_shape=(1,128,1))
x = Conv1D(8,3, activation='relu', padding='same',dilation_rate=2)(input_sig)
x1 = MaxPooling1D(2)(x)
x2 = Conv1D(4,3, activation='relu', padding='same',dilation_rate=2)(x1)
x3 = MaxPooling1D(2)(x2)
x4 = AveragePooling1D()(x3)
flat = Flatten()(x4)
encoded = Dense(2)(flat)
d1 = Dense(64)(encoded)
d2 = Reshape((16,4))(d1)
d3 = Conv1D(4,1,strides=1, activation='relu', padding='same')(d2)
d4 = UpSampling1D(2)(d3)
d5 = Conv1D(8,1,strides=1, activation='relu', padding='same')(d4)
d6 = UpSampling1D(2)(d5)
d7 = UpSampling1D(2)(d6)
decoded = Conv1D(1,1,strides=1, activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(d7)
model= Model(input_sig, decoded)
```